# Importing file format similar to csv file with | delimiters into Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a data format, that appears similar to a csv file, however has vertical bars between character strings, but not between Boolean fields. For example:

```
 |2000|,|code_no|,|first name, last name|,,,0,|word string|,0
 |2000|,|code_no|,|full name|,,,0,|word string|,0
```

I'm not sure what format this is (it is saved as a txt file). What format is this, and how would i import into python?

For referece, I had been trying to use:

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
    r = unicodecsv.reader(f)
```

And then stripping out the | from the start and end of the fields. This works ok, with the exception of fields which have a comma in them (e.g. `|first name, last name|` where the field gets split because of the comma.

Comment: Check the dox on the `reader` method and you'll have your answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the pipes are being used as quote characters, not delimiters. Have you tried initializing the `reader` to use pipe (`'|'`) as the quote character, and perhaps to use `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` as the quoting rules?

```
 csv.reader(f, quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')` ?

Comment: `delimiter=','` is the default, and can be omitted.

Comment: I took it straight from python documentation (and replaced the space with the comma).  Good catch!